# C# Prepared Statement Error - "could not find prepared statement with handle 1"

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I am looking at two forms that populate data from a database and I'm getting a "could not find prepared statement with handle 1" error on one of them. Based on what I've gathered from the other posts, that error is usually caused by either a version of SQL express running on their machines and/or the version of the .NET framework they're using.

Both statements are prepared select statements and are quite similar to each other but only the first one is throwing the error.

Aside from the tables and data involved, the only real difference between the two is that the first one (the one throwing the error) is also populated from a simple for loop (7 times) wherein one of the parameters is incremented by one.

Is there anything I'm missing? Are there any other possible reasons why that error is being produced aside from the SQL/.NET framework version being used by the machine?

Code1 throws "could not find prepared statement with handle 1"

```
c.Open();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(null, c);
command.CommandText = @"SELECT Patient.patientName + ' Gender:' + Patient.gender AS patient, Patient.patientName + ' [' + Patient.gender + '' + CAST(CAST(DATEDIFF(hour, Patient.birthdate, GETDATE()) / 8766.0 AS DECIMAL(4, 1)) AS VARCHAR(6)) + ']' AS patientSum, Patient.school, Patient.diagnosis, Patient.notes, Staff.staffName, Department.depName, Timeslot.time, CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), Schedule.date, 7) AS SchedDate, Schedule.notes, Contact.contactName, Contact.contactNo, Contact.email, Schedule.schedule_ID, Timeslot.timeslot_ID
FROM Timeslot LEFT OUTER JOIN Schedule ON (Timeslot.timeslot_ID = Schedule.timeslot_ID) AND (Schedule.date = @scheduleDate) AND Schedule.staff_ID = @scheduleStaff_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Staff ON Schedule.staff_ID = Staff.staff_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Department ON Staff.dep_ID = Department.dep_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Patient ON Schedule.patient_ID = Patient.patient_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Contact ON Patient.contact_ID = Contact.contact_ID;";

command.Parameters.Add("@scheduleDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = weekArray[ctr];
command.Parameters.Add("@scheduleStaff_ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = comboBox2.SelectedValue;

command.Prepare();
command.ExecuteReader();

SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
c.Close();
```

---

Code2 has no issues

```
c.Open();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(null, c);
command.CommandText = @"SELECT Patient.patient_ID, Patient.patientName, Patient.gender, CAST(DATEDIFF(hour, Patient.birthdate, GETDATE()) / 8766.0 AS DECIMAL(4, 1)) AS Age, Patient.birthdate, Patient.diagnosis, Patient.notes, Patient.school, Patient.referredBy, Patient.lastVisit, Patient.contact_ID, Contact.contactName, Contact.email, Contact.contactNo
FROM Patient INNER JOIN Contact ON Patient.contact_ID = Contact.contact_ID
WHERE Patient.patientName LIKE '%' + @patientName + '%'
OR Patient.diagnosis LIKE '%' + @diagnosis + '%'
OR Patient.notes LIKE '%' + @notes + '%'
ORDER BY Patient.patientName;";

command.Parameters.Add("@patientName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = textBox1.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@diagnosis", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Value = textBox1.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("@notes", SqlDbType.VarChar, 250).Value = textBox1.Text;

command.Prepare();
command.ExecuteReader();

SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
c.Close();
```

I should note by the way that the error is only produced by other machines without visual studio installed, the one I use for development throws no errors at all (all prerequisites are included in the installation i.e. .net framework, sql, powerpacks, etc.)

Comment: prepare is entirely optional, does it work if you comment out the line?

Comment: Actually as you close the connection straight after the call there is not much point in calling .prepare()

Comment: I don't know if the command Parameters are smart enough but, are you trying to insert a text value (comboBox2.SelectedValue (is a string?)) and mark it as an Integer?

Comment: The value is an integer (the id) while the displayed text is a text. For the other command parameters, in case you are wondering why they all use a similar textbox, the reason is simply to allow the user to search for a match from any of the three columns. I could have used a single command parameter for all three of them but simply coded it this way just because it "feels" more organized.

Comment: @Alex K. Yes, that did the trick. Any thoughts as to why it was necessary for me to remove .prepare in code1 but not in code2 even though it was simply optional? Also, kindly post it as an answer, thanks a lot!